# Android Studio - How To Save a Single Int?

Tags: java, android

I have a single Integer in my app that the user can click a button to add or subtract to. I want the Integer to keep it's value when the user exits and reopens the app. I have checked out SharedPrefrences and it was complicated and didn't make sense to me.

Comment: What didn't you understand in using SharedPreferences?! You have specific methods for reading and writing several types of key/value pairs. i.e.: `getInt()` and `putInt()`. When writing, you have to `apply()` or `commit()` the changes (the difference is that the former is asynchronous and the latter is synchronous). So, as usual, create the object, use it, and finally close it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Shared preferences example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Answer (score 1):

> I have checked out SharedPrefrences and it was complicated and didn't
>   make sense to me.

you have to handle the fact that there are not to many options...

1. store the info in the preferences
2. store the info in a DB you can
3. push that data into a server and hold it back

if you only need an integer value, then SharedPref is the most easy way to go....

how to write:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

how to read it back:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

official doc is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's few ways to store persistent information in an Android App

1. SharedPrefrences; this is the easiest way you can think off, without asking user for storage/network permissions

usage e.g.:-

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getInt("X", 1); // to retrieve 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).putInt("X", 1); // to store
```

2. File storage (internal/external); this is as easy as saving a text file in the internal or external storage, but does require user permission
3. SQLLite / other internal or external database service; this is as complicated as it gets, but this is more flexible